# jetpack compose has default toolbar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating new sample project with jetpack compose and i deleted xml theme from resources.

here is my `onCreate` method

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            topBar = {

            },
            content = {
                UiEntryPoint()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

and here is my `UiEntryPoint` method

```
@Composable
fun UiEntryPoint() {
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
    spec = LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(
        resId = R.raw.twitter_logo_motion
    )
)
val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
    composition = composition,
    isPlaying = true
)
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    LottieAnimation(
        modifier = Modifier.size(56.dp),
        composition = composition,
        progress = progress
    )
}
}
```

as you can see there is no `topBar` is my `Scaffold` but when I build the app I have a `Toolbar` like this

[image]

how can I remove the `ToolBar`

Comment: Specify `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` in you `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I added this line and i got this error `Cannot resolve symbol @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: @MohammadBaqer open your `themes.xml` file, change the `parent` attribute's last part to `NoActionBar`. Keep your `android:theme` as it was before.